# Activating a button only when CheckBox1 and CheckBox2 = True in Excel UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, userform

So I am trying to make a UserForm where if both checkboxes are marked the button will be allowed to be clicked.  I have tried a bunch of different code here is my first try.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If CheckBox1.Value = True & CheckBox2.Value = True Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = True
    Call GOGOGO
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = True & CheckBox2.Value = False Then
        MsgBox ("Run Characteristics Version 1.2.xlsm")
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = False & CheckBox2.Value = True Then
        MsgBox ("Log in")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Log in and Run Characteristics Version 1.2.xlsm")
End If

End Sub
```

Also Tried

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()

    'Evaluate the value of the CheckBox
    Select Case CheckBox1.Value
        Case True, False
    End Select

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_Change()

    'Evaluate the value of the CheckBox
    Select Case CheckBox2.Value
        Case True, False
    End Select

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Select Case CheckBox1.Value
    Select Case CheckBox2.Value
    If CheckBox1.Value = True & CheckBox2.Value = True Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = True
        Call GOGOGO
        ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = True & CheckBox2.Value = False Then
            MsgBox ("Run Characteristics Version 1.2.xlsm")
        ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = False & CheckBox2.Value = True Then
            MsgBox ("Log in")
        Else
            MsgBox ("Log in and Run Characteristics Version 1.2.xlsm")
    End If
    End Select
    End Select
    End Sub
```

Both only give me my first ElseIf.  So with all the different combinations of checkboxes when I click the commandbutton i always get msgBox "Run Characteristics...."

Question: How Can I make a button In Excel UserForm only Run a command when 2 checkboxes are marked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were **very** close, your challenge is simply that you used `&` rather than the VBA `And` operator.

For example, your first sub should look as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox2.Value = True Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = True
        Call GoGoGo
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox2.Value = False Then
        MsgBox ("Run Characteristics Version 1.2.xlsm")
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = True Then
        MsgBox ("Log in")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Log in and Run Characteristics Version 1.2.xlsm")
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that all I did was replace your `&` with the word `And`.

Hope that gives you what you need!!

Comment: Son of a B lol thanks man I was coding in JS all last week and threw this together yesterday lol.  thanks so much bro.

Comment: :) - Glad it proved to be a simple solution... Good luck with the rest of the code!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use '&' in if statement. It is used for string concatenation. This should make your code work. Also note that the enable comment is illogically placed, as the button is already pushed.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If (CheckBox1.Value And CheckBox2.Value) Then
    Call GOGOGO
else
    If not CheckBox1.Value  Then     
      If not CheckBox2.Value then
        MsgBox ("Log in and Run Characteristics Version 1.2.xlsm")
      else
        MsgBox ("Run Characteristics Version 1.2.xlsm")
      end if     
    else
        MsgBox ("Log in")
    end if  
end if

End Sub
```

For the 2nd method:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()

if CheckBox1.Value and CheckBox2.Value
   CommandButton1.Enabled = True
else
  CommandButton1.Enabled = False
end if

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_Change()

if CheckBox1.Value and CheckBox2.Value
    CommandButton1.Enabled = True
else
    CommandButton1.Enabled = False
end if

End Sub
```

But then you also have to initialize the commandbutton1